# building dynamic linq to sql queries

Tags: linq-to-sql, dynamic

I'm trying to create a Linq query based on a user's input.  Writing sql I could build a sql select string based upon the values selected but with linq to sql I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using linq to sql classes.  Here's what I have

```
        // Locals
        TalentDBDataContext talentDB = new TalentDBDataContext()
        int minAge = 0;
        int maxAge = 120;
        bool maleChecked = false;
        bool femaleChecked = false;
        List<string> ethnicities = new List<string>();
        List<string> states = new List<string>();

        var formData = Request.Form;
        foreach (string key in formData.AllKeys)
        {
            string val = formData[key];
            switch(key)
            {
                case "AgeMinTxBx":
                    minAge = Int32.Parse(val);
                    break;
                case "AgeMaxTxBx":
                    maxAge = Int32.Parse(val);
                    break;
                case "GenderMaleCB":
                    maleChecked = true;
                    break;
                case "GenderFemaleCB":
                    femaleChecked = true;
                    break;
                case "EthnicitySelector":
                    ethnicities = val.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                    break;
                case "StateSelector":
                    states = val.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        var results = 
            from t in talentDB.Talent
            (femaleChecked == true) ? where t.  // I don't thing this will work..
```

Is there a way I could do this? Hope this makes sense.   I like the intellisense linq provides and the error checking as well.  Perhaps there's still a way to write regular sql select string, and I could do it in this situation.  thanks

Comment: Show us you you want your query to look like (perhaps in SQL). Also, I find the foreach-switch construction a bit scary. Any reason you didn't just use: `minAge = int.Parse(formData["AgeMinTxBx"]);` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ExecuteQuery` method to directly execute a SQL query on that database.

Comment: Nice! that's cool.  Do you know if ExecuteQuery is supposed to be for efficient?

Comment: IEnumerable<Talent> tResults = talentDB.ExecuteQuery<Talent>("Select * from Talent");